# Output charger indications

Tags: charger

its a small question ...i got on my cell charger the indications as follow:

- **input**:100-240 V 50-60 Hz
- **output**: 5 V DC 1 A....

the question is what does the 1 A mean? i am new to circuits and etc..when plugging the cell then the current is created by the cell's total resistance and stuff so what does mean the 1 A mean in the charger indication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can imply a few things.

The 5V output will be guaranteed to be within tolerance (maybe +/-10%) when drawing a current of 1A from the device. That's about all that can be said without disecting the circuit in detail. For instance, at lower (or no-load) currents the 5V output might rise a bit to 6V or even higher. I would imagine this would be the case for a cell-phone charger.

Another example is the AC adapter for my yamaha piano - it says 12V on the side but off-load it's closer to 18V.

You also might be able to extract a little more than 1A as well but the voltage will probably be dropping towards 4 volts.

As I said before it's not guaranteed to mean much unless connected to the load it is intended.

Answer (score -1):

The maximum load you can connect is 1A. If it is a resistor, it can be not less than 5 ohms. also, assuming resistor wattage is more than 5 W.